# Saying 不是很多人 or 没有很多人 sounds clunky; how can I say "not many people" smoothly?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Sometimes I say 不是很多人 to mean "not many people"; it's basically a direct translation from English.  But it feels clunky to me, and I don't recall a native-Chinese speaker saying this.  I found an example of it used on [Line Dict](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/example/8823202fea3c4bf99088f6d2fda8a6c3/detail):

> 绿腰带**不是很多人**喜欢佩戴的。
>   **Not many people** like to wear green belts
>   <sub>lǜ yāodài **bùshì hĕnduō rén** xĭhuān pèidài de</sub>

I've heard native-Chinese speakers say 不多, but I wouldn't know how to adapt that.

I also found an example with 没有很多人 at [Line Dict](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/example/d518167e6f7f48b5bc0584733057023c/detail):

> 似乎这里**没有很多人**会手语
>   I don't meet a lot of people who sign here.
>    <sub>sìhū zhèlĭ **méiyŏu hĕnduō rén** huì shŏuyŭ</sub>

(Google Translate also suggests this.)

But this is just as clunky.  There's [很少人](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/example?query=%E5%BE%88%E5%B0%91%E4%BA%BA) (hěnshǎo rén) = "very few people", but it doesn't feel like it means "not many people".

**Question**: How can I say "not many people" smoothly?

Comment: to adapt 不多 users suggest feeding it to bkrs, find many suitable examples,esp.(1st 2 with 人）: 这种人毕竟不多,回来的人不多,他家人口不多,本书文字不多,我有几个，可是不多

Comment: To me, when using `不是很多` or `没有很多` to express the quantity, it do means `few`, `没多少` or `没几个` or `很少`. If the quantity is not that few, I may say `没太多`(not (too many)) or `也不是太多`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact IMO 不是很多人 and 没有很多人 both sound pretty natural to me, and I think they are the right translation of "not many people".

"绿腰带不是很多人喜欢佩戴的" sounds a bit odd but mainly that's because you would usually say "不是很多人喜欢佩戴绿腰带" or “喜欢佩戴绿腰带的人不多".

"似乎这里没有很多人会手语" sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: `不是很多人` 貌似是英翻汉的说法，我感觉`没多少人这么说`。类似的还有“请`停止`(Stop)伤害动物”，按接地气的说法，应该是“请`别再`伤害动物”…

Comment: 有时候会有这样的吧：“很多人喜欢吃香菜的吗？”“不是很多人吧”

Answer (score 6):

The way we express in Chinese is different.

"Not many people like to wear green belts" is a natural way in English. In Chinese, we say 喜欢扎绿色腰带的人不(是很)多。

"I don't meet a lot of people who sign here." We say this in Chinese: 我遇到过的人中会手语的不(是很)多。

Note that the structure is not necessarily agreed between the two languages while interpreting each other IMO. This is a good example to demonstrate this point.

Answer (score 3):

Both 不是很多人 and 没有很多人 are perfectly acceptable. However, if you want a more "fluid" version, you can use 没(有)多少人 or 几乎没(有)人. The latter is more like "almost no-one" while the former is "not many".

For example:

> 没有多少人喜欢佩戴绿腰带 / 几乎没人喜欢佩戴绿腰带
>
> 似乎这里没有多少人会手语 / 似乎这里几乎没人会手语

You could also rephrase the sentences and use 很少 or 不多 (this one is better) on the end, like:

> 似乎这里会手语的(人)不多 (the 人 is optional)

Answer (score 2):

In my teaching, I distinguish between grammatical usage and cultural/social usage.

For example, "I don't have enough money today":  我今天没有足够的钱 is grammatically correct (SVO construction), but people tend to say (cultural/social usage): 我今天的钱不够 (Topic Comment construction: topic 钱, comment 不够).

My explanation for the above is: the focus (not emphasis, as there are emphasis markers) is not on 我 (the sentence is not about "me") but on 钱 (the sentence is about "money").

Answer (score 1):

One simple way I heard being spoken in Taiwan is 人不多.
I'm not sure how correct this is, but I've heard phrases like 這裡(的)人不多
今天學生不多